# Isometric but differently shaped surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry

We have the following [chain of inclusions for surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76955/determining-a-surface-in-mathbbr3-by-its-gaussian-curvature/76957#76957) $M_1,M_2$:

> 1. $M_1,M_2$ have the same shape, i.e. are related by an ambient isometry
>     ⇆ $M_1,M_2$'s first and
>      second fundamental forms agree
> 2. → $M_1,M_2$ are isometric
>     ⇆ $M_1,M_2$'s first fundamental forms agree
> 3. → $M_1,M_2$ have the same Gaussian curvatures
> 4. → $M_1,M_2$ have the same genus (for closed surfaces)

In a more catchy way: **shape → metric → curvature → genus**

I know the standard examples of isometric but differently shaped surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$: plane, cone, cylinder.

> I am looking for (other) examples of
>
> - isometric but differently shaped surfaces (preferrably closed ones)
> - non-isometric surfaces with the same curvature

I assume there are no differently shaped surfaces isometric to the sphere, are there?

But what about other convex surfaces (with strictly positive but not constant curvature)? Or arbitrary surfaces homeomorphic to the sphere? Or to the torus?

(A picture gallery would be highly welcome, because I really would like to *see* two such (non-)isometric surfaces.)

Comment: Regarding your question of shape vs. metric, see Nash–Kuiper theorem (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem) that implies that every Riemannian manifold has very “strange/non-standard” isometric $C^1$-embeddings.

Comment: To complement the comment by @Yury, "reasonable" embeddings of convex surfaces indeed have the same shape. Pogorelov's uniqueness theorem applies to surfaces with "finite total extrinsic curvature", but unfortunately I forgot what this means, if I ever knew. It's mentioned in the Wikipedia article on [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_theorem_(geometry)).

Comment: @5pm: Thank you very much for the hint to Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @Yury: ... and thank *you* for the hint to Nash's theorem!

Comment: In 1, what do you mean by "first and second fundamental forms agree"?  I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I read it as "there is a diffeomorphism between two (embedded) surfaces that preserves both forms".

Comment: @5PM:  Then isn't 1. false?  Consider a long cylinder with spherical end caps (attached smoothly) and a short cylinder with the same radius with spherical end caps (attached in the same way)

Comment: @JasonDeVito These surfaces don't have the same area, so a diffeomorphism between them cannot preserve the first fundamental form.

Comment: @5PM:  Of course!  I was thinking of curvature and second fundamental form!

Comment: [Also on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123243/isometric-but-differently-shaped-closed-surfaces-in-mathbbr3)

Comment: I was about to offer a bounty for examples involving closed surfaces, but Robert Young and Deane Yang's comments on the MathOverflow question have covered all the cases I can think of.

Answer (score 5):

There is a continuous, isometric deformation between a [catenoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenoid) and a [helicoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid).

> [image]
>
> A parametrization of such a deformation is given by the system
>   $$\begin{align}
> x(u,v) &= \cos \theta \,\sinh v \,\sin u + \sin \theta \,\cosh v \,\cos u\\
> y(u,v) &= -\cos \theta \,\sinh v \,\cos u + \sin \theta \,\cosh v \,\sin u\\
> z(u,v) &= u \cos \theta + v \sin \theta \,
> \end{align}$$
>
> for $(u,v) \in (-\pi, \pi] \times (-\infty, \infty)$, with deformation parameter $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$, where $\theta = \pi$ corresponds to a right-handed helicoid, $\theta = \pm \pi / 2$ corresponds to a catenoid, and $\theta = 0$ corresponds to a left-handed helicoid.

In fact, there are lots of such [families of isometric minimal surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associate_family).

Comment: Thanks, these are good examples. But what about *closed* surfaces, do you know of any?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid not! Well, if you allow polyhedral surfaces, you can make a "house" by attaching a pyramid to the top face of a cube, and then get an isometric polyhedron by pushing the "roof" in. But this is probably not what you want.

Comment: Also, if I had clicked on the first link in your question sooner — instead of just now — I would have realized that you were probably already aware of the examples I gave. Sorry again. If you want, I can delete this answer.

Comment: Please, don't delete the answer, and thank you anyway. Would you go so far to assume that there are no isometric but differently shaped smooth *closed* surfaces? Would this be an interesting result?

Comment: I don't know nearly enough differential geometry to even guess, honestly!

Comment: In general, a closed smooth 2-manifold without a boundary can have many embeddings into ${\mathbb R}^3$. However, if its Gaussian curvature is positive then it has only one smooth embedding into ${\mathbb R}^3$ by the Cohn-Vossen theorem.